# Accessing Mule Flow's MuleContext in CXF Java class within Flow

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am trying to implement a CXF Server flow as below. I want to synchronously invoke the VM from the Java component (after CXF component). However to synchronously invoke the VM, I need MuleContext (for eg: muleContext.send("vm://some_name", MuleMessage)). I am currently stuck, unable to find a way to access the Mule Flow's MuleContext inside Java component within the Flow.
Any help is highly appreciated..

[Mule Flow Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1z1K.png)
Thanks,
Aneesh.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MuleSoft documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/java-component-reference on writing a Java Component.

If your Java class implements the org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable interface then you will be able to override the following method,

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext)
```

Inside this method you synchronously call the VM like this,

```
eventContext.sendEvent(message, endpoint)
```

Comment: Slight problem. The Java component after the CXF component (check my attached flow screenshot in my original post) is the class which is implementing the WS Interface (generated from WSDL). I am not sure how/where to add onCall() in that class...

Comment: Sorry I miss-understood. I would recommend not using your service implementation class (your java components next to the CXF) to orchestration your flow. You can even drop it all together if it's not needed. Instead use a vm:outbound-endpoint component to call your internal vm flow.

Comment: The problem that i face is - how to leverage mule out-of-the-box features (like db connections) to implement the wsdl operations. As i mentioned before, the java component after cxf is the impl class of cxf generated wsdl interface. Here mule/cxf framework automatically invokes the appropriate java method in the impl class (mapped one to one to wsdl operation) and automatically passes the soap request body as java method's i/p param. I have multiple operations defined in wsdl - problem is how to route to different vm's (with each vm implementing a wsdl operation)

Comment: After the CXF component you can read the "cxf_operation" flow variable and add a choice router against the "localPart" attribute. You will then be able to route to whatever vm you want.